# c++ overloading += operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class:

```
class MyClass{

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;

    public:

    MyClass(double _a, double _b, double _c, double _d){
        a = _a;
        b = _b;
        c = _c;
        d = _d;
    }

   MyClass operator+=(const MyClass & rhs){
    a += rhs.a;
    b += rhs.b;
    c += rhs.c;
    d += rhs.d;
    return this;
    }

    MyClass operator+(MyClass & rhs){
      MyClass newOne(a+rhs.a,b+rhs.b,c+rhs.c,d+rhs.d);
    return newOne;
}
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
MyClass my1(1., 2., 3., 4.);
MyClass my2(2., 3., 4., 5.);
MyClass my3(2., 4., 6., 8.);
my2 += my3;
my1 += my2;
```

and this one is working, but when I use it like this

```
my1 += my2 += my3;
```

i get diffrent answer.
And how can I make to count expression in brackets as first? For example :

```
(my1 + my2) + my3 == my1 + (my2 + my3)
```

Comment: `MyClass operator+=(const MyClass & rhs){` should be `MyClass & operator+=(const MyClass & rhs){`. `return this;` should be `return *this;`

Comment: `return this;` won't compile.

Comment: `i get wrong answer` <--- What did you expect? What are you getting?

Comment: What results do you get? Op += should be RL-associative.

Comment: changing according to your suggestions helped, thanks a lot. But how can I solve second problem? Should I  overload ()?

Comment: @user932: It's not at all clear what your last question means. The parenthesised expressions will be evaluated before the larger expressions they're part of, if that's what you mean, since that's what the parentheses are for. If you mean something else, then please give a clear example.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what result are you expecting to get in this statement

```
my1 += my2 += my3;
```

The statement is equivalent to

```
my1 += ( my2 += my3 );
```

According to the C++ Standard (5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators)

> 1 The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   **all group right-to-left**.

The valid operator definition will look like

```
MyClass & operator +=( const MyClass & rhs )
{
    a += rhs.a;
    b += rhs.b;
    c += rhs.c;
    d += rhs.d;

    return *this;
}
```

Take into account that there are several typos in your code. For example in the operator instead of this you have to return *this or the class definition shall be ended with a semicolon after the closing brace.

As for this expression

```
(my1 + my2) + my3 == my1 + (my2 + my3)
```

then it is entirely unclear what you are trying to achieve. There is no defined comparison operator for your class.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- First, `operator+=` should return a *reference* to the value
  it modifies, not a copy; the return type should be
  `MyClass&`.
- And `operator+` should take a reference to const, not to
  non-const; you can't bind a temporary to a reference to
  a non-const.

Classically, `operator+` will be a free function, along the
lines of:

```
MyClass operator+( MyClass const& lhs, MyClass const& rhs )
{
    MyClass results( lhs );
    results += rhs;
    return results;
}
```

This is done to ensure that the same conversions will be applied
to the operands on both sides of the `+`; since your class
doesn't support any conversions, it doesn't matter, but it's
a good habit to get into.

Comment: Return type should not be const!

Comment: @NeilKirk Oops.  You're right, I mis-typed.  Fixed.